# Error in moshi android, cannot run on kitkat devices

Tags: kotlin, moshi

the project can generate apk and can be used from kitkat to oreo but after upgrading android studio and started using androidx, the following problem occurs. it happens only in kitkat after enabling minifyEnabled=true shrinkResources=true

```
java.lang.VerifyError: com/squareup/moshi/kotlin/reflect/KotlinJsonAdapter$IndexedParameterMap
    at com.squareup.moshi.kotlin.reflect.KotlinJsonAdapter.fromJson(KotlinJsonAdapter.kt:111)
    at com.squareup.moshi.internal.NullSafeJsonAdapter.fromJson(NullSafeJsonAdapter.java:40)
    at com.squareup.moshi.kotlin.reflect.KotlinJsonAdapter.fromJson(KotlinJsonAdapter.kt:84)
    at com.squareup.moshi.internal.NullSafeJsonAdapter.fromJson(NullSafeJsonAdapter.java:40)
    at com.squareup.moshi.JsonAdapter$2.fromJson(JsonAdapter.java:161)
    at com.squareup.moshi.JsonAdapter$3.fromJson(JsonAdapter.java:197)
    at com.squareup.moshi.JsonAdapter$1.fromJson(JsonAdapter.java:108)
    at retrofit2.converter.moshi.MoshiResponseBodyConverter.convert(MoshiResponseBodyConverter.java:45)
    at retrofit2.converter.moshi.MoshiResponseBodyConverter.convert(MoshiResponseBodyConverter.java:27)
    at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.parseResponse(OkHttpCall.java:223)
    at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.execute(OkHttpCall.java:186)
    at com.jakewharton.retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.CallObservable.subscribeActual(CallObservable.java:41)
    at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:12267)
    at com.jakewharton.retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.BodyObservable.subscribeActual(BodyObservable.java:34)
    at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:12267)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableSingleSingle.subscribeActual(ObservableSingleSingle.java:35)
    at io.reactivex.Single.subscribe(Single.java:3603)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleSubscribeOn$SubscribeOnObserver.run(SingleSubscribeOn.java:89)
    at io.reactivex.Scheduler$DisposeTask.run(Scheduler.java:578)
    at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.run(ScheduledRunnable.java:66)
    at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.call(ScheduledRunnable.java:57) 
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:152) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:265) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:864)
```

and here is my proguard rules

```
-dontwarn kotlin.**
-dontwarn kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.**
-keep class kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.** { *; }

-keep class kotlin.Metadata { *; }

-keepclassmembers class kotlin.Metadata {
    public <methods>;
}

-dontwarn org.jetbrains.annotations.**

-keep class kotlin.** { *; }
-dontwarn kotlin.**
-keepclassmembers class **$WhenMappings {
    <fields>;
}

-keep class com.squareup.moshi.kotlin.reflect.** { *; }
-keep class com.squareup.moshi.internel.** { *; }

-keepclassmembers class com.squareup.moshi.kotlin.reflect.** { *; }
-keepclassmembers class com.squareup.moshi.internel.** { *; }

-keepclassmembers class * {
    @com.squareup.moshi.FromJson <methods>;
    @com.squareup.moshi.ToJson <methods>;
}

-dontwarn javax.annotation.**

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    @com.squareup.moshi.* <methods>;
}

-keep class **JsonAdapter {
    <init>(...);
    <fields>;
}

-keep @com.squareup.moshi.JsonQualifier interface *

-keepclassmembers @com.squareup.moshi.JsonClass class * extends java.lang.Enum {
    <fields>;
    **[] values();
}

-keep public class kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.builtins.* { public *; }

-keep public class kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.** { public *; }
```

i have tried other references like https://github.com/square/moshi/issues/803 but i found no answer in this. please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be Kotlin issue, as a workaround use `Moshi 1.6.0` and `Proguard` instead of `R8` -> `android.enableR8=false`